# Global CONSTANTS. Any problem using them?

Tags: matlab, global-variables, constants, global, simulink

I've been programming for over 6 years now and i've always avoided using global variables because there is always another way around the problems.

Today, i work on a (big) project, we want to use a dictionnary of mathematical CONSTANTS what will never be modified anywhere. The only problem i seem to find with globals on internet is the fact that if someone overwrites one it could bug out the whole project. But as mine are constants this problem doesnt apply.

(as a second security to avoid people creating a variable with the same name as one of the constants i will probably pack them all in a single global struct)

Does anyone know of problems that still happend using global constants?

Thanks for your answers! :)

Comment: How do you know that nobody will get lost in the big project and overwrite it in the future?

Comment: Because to edit it you would have to type something along the lines of "constantsDictionnary.pi = 5;"
There's no way you wouldn't realise you are overwritting the constants doing that.

Comment: I honestly don’t see a problem with such a global other than that it might slow down execution of code that uses it. Globals in MATLAB are said to slow down the JIT because it cannot make assumptions about the values or types. If you are looking to convert to C, this is a moot point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old-fashioned standard way to create a constant in MATLAB is to [write a function](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/09/13/constants/). For example [`pi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pi.html) is a function. It could be written as:

```matlab
function value = pi
value = 3.14159;
end
```

Of course we can overwrite the value of `pi` in MATLAB, but it is always a local change, it is not possible to affect another workspace.

Comment: Yes this is the best solution i found yet from the sources i collected.
The class solution would have been nice but Matlab Coder uses C code and does not recognize the C++ Class concept.
the way i am planning to implement this is
```
function value = const
value = struct (...
         "constant1" , 1 ,...
         "pi" , 3.14159265358979323 ,...
         "constant2" , 8);
end
```

Comment: After thinking about this solution, it would mean i have to call that function everytime i want to use my constants this is very bad on processing time.

So i am now looking for a way to use header files in matlab/simulink and generate my code using the header file i created myself but it seems it is not possible to set constants in a header and import it into matlab. 

I will keep updating you guys about my researches!

if anyone has leads please be sure to comment!

Comment: @Hood: I wouldn't worry about processing time until you've tried it and timed it. I'm fairly sure that the JIT optimizes away the function call, and expect that MATLAB Coder would be able to do similarly.

Comment: I don't have experience with the MATLAB Coder, only worked with another C-Code generator so far. The way I would go there would be to force inline the function. I am sure the MATLAB Coder has similar options.

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, your best bet for mathematical constants is to define a class with properties that have the `Constant` attribute. This is described in the doc [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-with-constant-values.html), and here's the leading example from that page:

```
classdef NamedConst
   properties (Constant)
      R = pi/180
      D = 1/NamedConst.R
      AccCode = '0145968740001110202NPQ'
      RN = rand(5)
   end
end
```

This way, the values cannot be overridden. (Note that there's something a little perhaps unexpected in this example - the value of the property `RN` changes each time the class is loaded! I personally wouldn't write code like that...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Edric! I didnt find such a solution anywhere else, i will look into it.
But another thing about my project is that i will generate my code into C using matlab coder.

To avoid matlab coder doing what ever it wants i would like to import a .h file into matlab containing my constants, that way matlab coder would be forced to use my header file exactly as it is.

Comment: I know it is possible to import global variables in MATLAB using a header file. I will also look into the possiility of defining such a class in a header file and import it into matlab, but if you have the answer i am all ears! :)

Comment: After testing, it turns out class object are not generable as matlab coder uses C language and classes are a C++ feature